# How to convert from ref ^ pointer to raw pointer?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, c++-cx

In WindowsRT / Metro, how can I convert a ref ^ pointer to a raw pointer?

For example, I want to pass a pointer to a control through to an old C-style callback, which expects the parameter to be `void*`:

`// this = type derived from Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page

SetCallback(this);`

However, I get an error:

> cannot convert parameter 1 from 'MyProject::MainPage ^const ' to 'void *'

How can I convert `MainPage` to a raw pointer (without C-style / reinterpret_casts)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `T^` may be converted to its corresponding pointer type `T*` using `reinterpret_cast`<sup>(*)</sup>.  The simplest, correct code would be to convert the `T^` to a `Object^` then cast to `IInspectable*`:

```
IInspectable* AsInspectable(Platform::Object^ o)
{
    return reinterpret_cast<IInspectable*>(o);
}
```

`IInspectable*` is convertible to `void*`, though you do need to be mindful of the COM lifetime rules (I don't know what you are planning to do with this `void*`, so I cannot make any concrete suggestions here).

I discussed the hat in some detail in my article ["Types That Wear Hats."](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/09/17/cxxcxpart02typesthatwearhats.aspx)  You may find some of that information helpful.

---

(*) You ask for a way to do this without `reinterpret_cast`, but that restriction makes no sense:  `reinterpret_cast` is the supported way to perform this conversion.

Comment: The `reinterpret_cast` comment is because I was under the impression that `reinterpret_cast` is only used for unrelated types, and if they're unrelated, you should really think twice before using it. I first tried `static_cast` but that didn't work, obviously. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. :-)  In this case, `reinterpret_cast` is the right answer.

Comment: Please also note that this is only supported for `T^` to `T*`, you can get yourself into trouble if you reinterpret_cast `Canvas^` to a `ICanvas*`, you must first safe_cast/static_cast `Canvas^` to `ICanvas^`, then you can reinterpret_cast `ICanvas^` to `ICanvas*`.

Comment: Also note, there are exceptions to `T^` -> `T*`.  For example: `Platform::String^` can be reinterpret casted to `HSTRING` and `Object^` can be reinterpret casted to `IInspectable*`.

Comment: @BobFincheimer:  Right, there are complexities and subtleties, which is why I recommend `Object^` -> `IInspectable*` for a general-purpose solution (it works for all interface and runtime class hats, which is what is being dealt with in most cases).  Note that `Canvas^` -> `ICanvas*` is actually correct because `ICanvas` is the default interface of `Canvas`.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis i picked the wrong example, maybe I should have done `DependencyObject^` -> `IDependencyObject*`.